# Man wearing simple women jeans?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, women, men, clothing

Is it permissible for a man to wear women jeans (that is only simple one without any designs and other things)? 
As, sometimes, the material is very comfortable and they costs less.

Comment: Are they tight jeans? As it is forbidden for men to wear tight clothing in Islam (`تبرج`).

Comment: thanks for the reply, no its loose jeans. can you give any hadith reference?

Comment: This question shows no research effort at all. I would strongly suggest you check the advice in our help centre http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to better understand the Stack Exchange model and the sorts of questions we encourage here.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not allowed. 
There are 6 criterias for dressing up in Islam, and one of them is: a man shouldn't wear the dress of a woman and a woman shouldn't wear the dress of a man. 
Hence it's not allowed. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but it doesn't relate to it as its not a dress. just a simple jeans and its for use in house only. kindly reply, if possible with hadith reference.